# How can I make show score show a text message if certain amount of scores is met?

Tags: javascript, html

just using my quarantine time to learn html and javascript. I have a question. I try making a quiz program using other people free code in internet.

```
function showScores() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};
```

I want to change this show score function so that they will show a text message if they got certain amount of score. how can I do that?

Comment: Can you be more specificf? You want to show a message ***and*** the above, or just a message? Show a message if they get *what* score exactly? Have you tried adding a message? What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Just define a **minScore** variable and give it a value (let's say 10)

Now you can just use an if statement to accomplish what you want:

```
if(quiz.score > minScore) {
  console.log('Congratulations, You won'); // you can print whatever you want.
}
```

Now if player's score would be greater than 10, then this message will get printed in the console.